# How to rotate the view in iOS5?

Tags: xcode, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller

I have used a `splitviewController` in my application. The orientation of the app is strictly set to landscape. I have done it properly in the build settings.

When I run my app in iOS 5.1 or greater, it works nicely. But when I run my app in iOS 5 or less, the orientation of the app is not changed to landscape. It's a big problem. Is there any solution?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: try `return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));`

Answer (score 1):

Use this in all `viewControllers` for `orientation`

```
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   // Return YES for supported orientations
   [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
   return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Insert the following instead:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
```

statement with

```
return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight));
```